# Prisma type-checking fails for destructured and appended objects

Tags: node.js, typescript, type-conversion, destructuring, prisma

I'm using [Prisma](https://prisma.io) as a type-safe ORM within my typescript node environment. When I pass a restructured object to an update call

```
const params = {incorrect_param: true};
const data = await prisma.document.update({
    where: { id },
    data: {
      ...params,
      // verified: true,   // when this is uncommented, type-checking fails
    },
  });
```

it correctly highlights that `params` is not the right type to update the document. However when I uncomment the `updated_at` line, the errors go away and it fails to typecheck at all. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? The error occurs when any additional line is added beyond the restructured `params` object.

For context, my schema for document is as follows:

```
model identity_document_verification {
  id                  BigInt     @id @default(autoincrement())
  created_at          DateTime   @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updated_at          DateTime   @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  user_id             String     @db.Uuid
  submission_id       BigInt     @unique(map: "idv_i_submission_id") @default(autoincrement())
  verified   Boolean?
  submission          submission @relation(fields: [submission_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  user                user       @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
}
```

I'm on `prisma@3.5.0` and `next@11.1`. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would you share your Prisma Schema and the type/content of `params`, so one could replicate the issue?

Comment: @TasinIshmam I've updated my question to include an example for `params` and my schema

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I can replicate the problem. Would you kindly create a [bug report](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) with all the details mentioned here for replication? That way, we could have someone look into it when possible.

Comment: By the way, I could only replicate this issue for the `update` query and not anything else (`create`, `delete`, etc). Is it the same for you?